# Can SUBSTITUTE be used with OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this in a cell:

```
max - new york
```

I can use `SUBSTITUTE(A1;" ";"")` to remove the spaces.

Can I use `OR` in `SUBSTITUTE` to remove the spaces *and* the `dash(-)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But you *can* call recursively:

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;" ";""); "-"; "")
```